# attach tow string-array to listView

Tags: arrays, android-studio, listview, android-arrayadapter

i have three string-array in String Resources of the app, and I want to show all in a listview using an adapter contains three textView

```
    String [] Names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Names);
    String [] Num = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.num);
    String [] Date = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date);

    ArrayAdapter arraydb1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter, R.id.txtvName, Names);
    ArrayAdapter arraydb2 = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter, R.id.txtvNum, Num);
    ArrayAdapter arraydb3 = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter, R.id.txtvDate, Date);

    lstFiles.setAdapter(arraydb1);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any array to the corresponding textView.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Names.length; i++) {
        textView.setText()
    }
```